# AccessViolationException in debugger with only managed code and WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, access-violation

This application has a WCF web service that is called by a WinForms app.  The WinForms app has a class `WCFCache` to manage data from the service.  There is a section like this in that class to manage an optional custom configuration section that a subset of the machines have:

```
private bool? m_HasCustomConfiguration = null;
public bool HasCustomConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        if (m_HasCustomConfiguration == null)
            m_HasCustomConfiguration = (CustomConfiguration != null);
        return (bool)m_HasCustomConfiguration;
    }
}

private WCFService.CustomConfiguration m_CustomConfiguration = null;
public WCFService.CustomConfiguration CustomConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        if (m_CustomConfiguration == null)
        {
            if (m_HasCustomConfiguration.HasValue
                && !m_HasCustomConfiguration.Value)
                return null;
            try
            {
                using (WCFService.WCFServiceClient wcf = new WCFService.WCFServiceClient())
                {
                    m_CustomConfiguration = 
                        wcf.GetCustomConfiguration(Machine.ProcessID);
                        // Above method returns null if no record exists.
                    m_HasCustomConfiguration = (m_CustomConfiguration != null);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Error logging & re-throw
            }
        }
        return m_CustomConfiguration;
    }
}
```

When I step through the debugger in code that calls either of the above properties like this:

```
if (!Program.WCFCache.HasCustomConfiguration)
    return new List<CustomComponents>();
```

...it throws the following exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message="Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
Source="System.Windows.Forms"
...
```

When I step *onto* the line containing the reference, there is a long pause, followed by a VS popup with the exception.

The exception doesn't appear when I just put a breakpoint after the above code has executed.  It doesn't even appear when I put a breakpoint inside the accessors of the properties.  It only occurs when I step onto a line with one of those properties from the outside.  (So there is a workaround, but it can be a pain.)

Why is this happening?  Can I stop it?

Edit: The whole application was written in the last year in 3.5 C#/.NET with WCF communicating between components; meaning, we don't have legacy unmanaged DLLs.  Just two unmanaged calls: one to advapi32.dll when the WinForms app is loading, in the username detection procedure.  The issue I'm having happens only in this one place in the code, in a place that is about as unrelated to the login section as you can get.  The other is to kernel32.dll, in a GC force-flush long *after* anything is done with the results from calls like the one above.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, is the logic in `HasCustomConfiguration` inverted? The name of the member suggests that it should be `true` when `CustomConfiguration != null`, but the logic is backwards.

Comment: Correct.  That was a typo in my transcription.  :)  Fixed.

Comment: Probably not the cause of the crash, but your getter for HasCustomConfiguration doesn't return a value.

Comment: Another transcription typo.  Another edit fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found that others have encountered this situation and that it is likely a Visual Studio bug.  I was using VS 2008 when the problem occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any P/Invoke or other such native code? Odds are, that's where you should start looking.

This exception is a symptom of a larger problem, namely memory corruption (that what the exception says, after all). If this was a native application, you'd get a crash.

So, look at any native calls, make sure they're operating correctly, maybe run them under a debugger to try and trap the error closer to home.

Sorry, can't really give better advice given the circumstances.

Comment: There's only one Form in the app that uses Invokes -- for worker thread callbacks -- and this isn't it.

The whole application is greenfield development within in the last year -- all 3.5 C#/.NET with WCF between components.  No legacy unmanaged code.  Edited to make that more explicit in the question as well.

Comment: Huh... any `unsafe` code? Or, any third-party libraries? Honestly, pure CLR code should never, in the absence of hardware failure, cause an `AccessViolationException`. Either there is some buggy native code somewhere, your processor is fried (which would be indicated by other programs crashing randomly), or you've uncovered a previously untested corner case... Which I doubt...

Comment: No `unsafe` code.  No 3rd party libraries in the WinForms app or Web Service.  And it always happens only in the debugger at lines that reference the above properties. Hence why I'm stumped by this one.  :)